# How do I access image files

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-processing

So I was trying to open image files in google collab. My target is to apply FFT for image processing. Here i have files labelled as array values. How exactly would I access an image instead of the numerical values.

```
!nvidia-smi
!nvidia-smi
!nvidia-smi 
!pip install tensorflow-gpu
!pip install tensorflow_hub
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import cv2

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
    
data_root='/content/drive/My Drive/ML/AlpDatabase/DATASET'
   
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('/content/drive/My Drive/ML/AlpDatabase/DATASET')
    

data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
    
batch = data_iterator.next()
    
batch[0].shape
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
    for idx, img in enumerate(batch[0][:4]):
      ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
      ax[idx].title.set_text(batch[1][idx])
```

so if I had to print a certain image from data set how would I accomplish that as my goal is to send the image files to my FFT algorithm and then create a new dataset after processing. My goal here was to basically read image files from my drive folder maintain classes.

My drive folder has DATASET folder containing A,B,C,D.... etc folders each with many images. Basically an image dataset of alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly - You want to basically read image files from the drive folder maintain classes.

The code mentioned above is working fine to do the same when I tried replicating the issue. Please check this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/4cdeb5a92b485a92cf0e01daee8062c8/74791529.ipynb) for your reference.

You also can use the below code to display images after fetching from the directory where class_names will be your DATASET inside folder names (A,B,C,D...).

```
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('/content/drive/My Drive/MY WORK/dataset/flowers')

class_names = data.class_names
print(class_names)
```

Output:

```
['daisy', 'dandelion', 'rose', 'sunflower', 'tulip'] #in your case ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'...
```

To display images:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in data.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")
```

Output:

[image]